# Abrir un layout para registro

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Añadí mi app a cuentas del movil para poder hacer un auto login sin necesidad de introducir credenciales.
A la hora de acceder a la sección del móvil cuentas añado mi app, pero se abre y cierra es como si no me abriera el layout.

**account_preference.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="General Settings" />
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="account_settings"
    android:title="Account Settings"
    android:summary="Sync frequency, notifications, etc." >
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.pargibay.androidphprpcxml"
        android:targetClass="com.example.pargibay.androidphprpcxml.AccountAuthenticatorSimpleActivity" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**authenticator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="com.example.pargibay.androidphprpcxml"
android:icon="@drawable/logoapp"
android:smallIcon="@drawable/logoapp"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:accountPreferences="@xml/account_preference"
/>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
       <service
        android:name=".AccountAuthenticatorService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":auth">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>
```

En la clase donde quiero que haga el registro de las cuentas

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_manager_simple);

    textuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textUser);
    textpass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPassword);
    txtuser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
    txtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPass);

    username = txtuser.getText().toString().trim();
    password = txtpass.getText().toString().trim();

    accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    //username = settings.getString("userName", "");

    if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        requestLogin();
    }else{
        Account[]accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(getResources().getString(R.string.account_type));
        if(accounts.length <= 0){
            requestLogin();
        }else{
            accountFound = false;
            for(Account account : accounts){
                if(account.name.equals(username)){
                    accountFound = true;
                    authToken = getAuthToken(account);
                    loginWithUserNameAuthToken(username, authToken);
                }
            }
            if(!accountFound){
                requestLogin();
            }
        }
    }


}

private void requestLogin(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Algo ha ido mal, inicie sesión por favor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private String getAuthToken(Account account) {
    return "";
}

private void loginWithUserNameAuthToken(String userName, String authToken) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Login with the user name \"" + userName + "\" and the authToken \"" + authToken);
}
}
```

Y este es la clase Servicio:

```
public class AccountAuthenticatorService extends Service {

private static final String LOG_TAG = AccountAuthenticatorService.class.getSimpleName();
private static AccountAuthenticatorImpl sAccountAuthenticator = null;

public AccountAuthenticatorService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    IBinder ret = null;
    if (intent.getAction().equals(android.accounts.AccountManager.ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT)) {
        ret = getAuthenticator().getIBinder();
    }
    return ret;
}

public AbstractAccountAuthenticator getAuthenticator() {
    if (AccountAuthenticatorService.sAccountAuthenticator == null) {
        AccountAuthenticatorService.sAccountAuthenticator = new AccountAuthenticatorImpl(this);
    }
    return AccountAuthenticatorService.sAccountAuthenticator;
}

private static class AccountAuthenticatorImpl extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
    private Context mContext;

    public AccountAuthenticatorImpl(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        Bundle reply = new Bundle();
        return reply;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String[] features) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

A mi me parece que tengo algo mal en el xml account_preference.xml o me falta. La idea que tengo es cuando quieras añadir una cuenta selecciones mi app y te salga la ventana de añadir cuenta y que la registre pero esa ventana no sale.

Comment: Te sale algun error en el logcat? podrias por favor ponerlo aqui

Comment: Como comenta bruno es importante revisar el LogCat, debe ser un error en el servicio.

Comment: En el logcat no sale ningún error le doy a añadir cuentas desde el sistema android no desde la propia app y nada, hace el intento de abrir una ventana pero es como si no encontrase.